# Growth with restrictions (finding maxvalue of constant term)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, logistic-regression

I have the following differencial ekvation that shows the population change for fish, where x is a constant death rate by accident. How can I determine the maximum value of x so that the fish population wont die out in the future?
$$
n'(t)=0.12(1-(n(t)/10000))\cdot n(t)-x,\\
 n(0)=250000.
$$

Comment: Well, if the value is continuous, then the time derivative is zero at the maximum. Can you work it out now?

Comment: I get x to -720 000 and it cant be true because the death rate cant be negative....

Comment: What's $x$ in the equation?

Comment: It is a constant value that wont change. Deaths by accident per year

Comment: That sounds like a very bad model, then. Surely accidents would happen on a per-fish basis, i.e., the "x" term should be something like $C \cdot n(t)$, where $C$ is the per-fish probability of an accident. Are you required to use this model for some reason (i.e., is it a homework problem)? Because if it's actually a research task, I strongly recommend reconsidering the model.

Comment: I know hahaha, yea it just has to be done. It an example from a textbook. I need to understand this in order to complite a similar task at test. Would be gratefull if you could help me with this one so I could follow the same path.

Comment: ahhh n(0) = 4000

Comment: that gives x= 288 right?

Comment: With some numerical inspections, I get that for not too small integration time steps, the maximum $x$ is $300$. If I switch it to $301$, it quite quickly dies out. The final value for me settles to about $5~000$.

Comment: Thought: In the stable case, where the population is not changing as a function of time, also the time derivative of the population is not changing! Therefore, you can calculate $n''(t) $...